# duplicate numbers in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to find duplicate numbers in arraylist. Arraylist contains {1.A, 2.B, 3.C, 3.D, 4.A...}I want to print duplicate values like 3.C 3.D.Can you help me please how can I print duplicate values in arraylist?

```
        while (scRef.hasNext()) {
            word1 = scRef.next();     
            listRef.add(word1);
        }
        while (scStud.hasNext()) {
            word2 = scStud.next();     
            listStud.add(word2);
        }

        for ( int i=0; i<listRef.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < listStud.size(); j++)
            if (listRef.get(i).equals(listStud.get(j))) {
                ccount++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Help you do what? What is your question?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1393766)

Comment: You have two lists. What are the contents of both?

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis example of my arraylist is like {1.A, 2.A, 2.B, 3.D..} Second questions like 2.A, 2.B is duplicate. I want to print like this duplicated values.